# How to read several lines from text file into memory?

Tags: java, memory-management, parsing

I have a file with the structure like so: http://gamedev.pastebin.com/8iESYTVY 
but it's much bigger in size, 233MB, how can I read blocks of lines, enough lines to 
 represent 10MB, into memory so I won't have to read in the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Java nio](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html), which allow random access to a file. Or, in other words, allows mapping a file to memory, allowing your Java program to access it permanently at random locations.